# Code that prints random words at table columns

Tags: java

code that should print cs randomly at any four different columns as the picture

[image: Android]

[image: Androids]

Code that does that it should print cs randomly at any four columns

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{

    BufferedWriter bw = null;        
    FileWriter fw = null; 

    try 
    {           
        fw = new FileWriter("F:\\Android.html");
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                    String Word = "Android";                        

                    String[] Words = new String[4];
                    Words[0] = "CS";
                    Words[1] = "";
                    Words[2] = "";
                    Words[3] = "";                         

                    List<String> Android = Arrays.asList(Words);
                    Collections.shuffle(Android);

                    bw.write("<Table align ='center' border = '4'>");   
                    bw.write("<TR>"); 

                    bw.write("<TD width='45'>");                      
                    bw.write(Android.toString());                                
                    bw.write("</TD>");                         

                    bw.write("<TD width='45'>");                      
                    bw.write(Android.toString());                                
                    bw.write("</TD>");                        

                    bw.write("<TD width='45'>");                      
                    bw.write(Android.toString());   
                    bw.write("</TD>");

                    bw.write("<TD width='45'>");                      
                    bw.write(Android.toString());                         
                    bw.write("</TD>");                        

                    bw.write("<TD width='45'>");                      
                    bw.write(Android.toString());                         
                    bw.write("</TD>");   

                    bw.write("</TR>");    
                    bw.write("<Table>");  
                    }
```

the code prints

[image]

a few configuration changes should sort that

Comment: Looks like you forgot to ask a question?

Comment: the cuestion is that the result espected is as earlier picture but is as later picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String filePath = "E:\\Android.html";
        try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath))) {
            String Word = "Android";
            String[] Words = new String[4];
            Words[0] = "CS";
            Words[1] = "";
            Words[2] = "";
            Words[3] = "";
            List<String> Android = Arrays.asList(Words);
            Collections.shuffle(Android);
            bw.write("<Table align ='center' border = '4'>");
            bw.write("<TR>");
            bw.newLine();
            for (String str : Android) {
                bw.write("<TD width='45'>");
                bw.write(str);
                bw.write("</TD>");
                bw.newLine();
            }
            bw.write("</TR>");
            bw.write("<Table>");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> Output

*Run 1*

[image: Run 1]

*Run 2*

[image: Run 2]

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the four repeated blocks of:

```
bw.write("<TD width='45'>");                      
bw.write(Android.toString());                                
bw.write("</TD>");
```

with:

```
for(String cell: Android) {
     bw.write("<TD width='45'>");                      
     bw.write(cell);                                
     bw.write("</TD>");                        
}
```

Your problem was writing the entire list to each cell, rather than just one element per cell.

As an aside, I would suggest choosing a more descriptive name than `Android` for your list of strings, and the convention in java is to begin variable names with lower case letters.  (Uppercase names are typically reserved for classes.)